# Silverlight Mass Photo Uploader eats extremely big amount of RAM

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, ram, photo-upload

I'm building a Silverlight app where users select photos from their computer, edit an associated title/description/tags etc. and then upload to a web server via WCF. Actually everything's working perfectly just with a *little* problem. I want to show the thumbnails of the photos in a list before uploading, and to achieve that, the only way I know is to load the file and then process it. If the users selects about 20 files, `sllauncher.exe` eats huge amount of RAM, around a gigabyte (well it could be more than normal for Photoshop/3ds max, or Firefox that has run for an half an hour, but it IS too much for a web photo uploader app), and when I try to upload the images, the app even tries to load more and crashes completely. I want to be able to upload more photos, like a hundred or more, at a time, but how can I achieve that *while still having the thumbnail functionality*? One thing is queuing the uploads and therefore the loading of the files, but it would cause the thumbnails also not to load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd load the picture after it has been added to the application, get the thumbnail and unload the picture - then the user may enter his information on the picture. When it's completed, the original file is put in a queue for upload. That way, only two pictures at once are handled at max, thus freeing the memory from unneeded data.